# How to load different Bloginfo value for top level pages?

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

I am no PHP programmer therefore I have been scratching my head for two hours on this issue as there seems to be many ways of doing it. None of which I managed to get working because of my poor PHP/Wordpress syntax and logic knowledge.

What is the best way to create and call a function that loads a different value for `<?php bloginfo('name') ?>` only on top level pages? i.e. top level menu headings.

I was wondering if there would be the possibility of doing something along these lines:

```
<?php

if ( is_page( 'about' ) || == $post->post_parent ) {    
bloginfo = 'about';

} elseif ( is_page( 'work' ) || == $post->post_parent ) {   
bloginfo = 'work';

} elseif ( is_page( 'contact' ) || == $post->post_parent ) {    
    bloginfo = 'contact';

} else { 
  bloginfo('name');
}   

?>
```

Please treat it as pseudo code as I am still familiarizing myself with the wordpress and PHP codex/syntax, hence why I cannot get anything to work. But basically, what I need to do is use the main nav link names as the bloginfo name for every page in their section. Anything else is an exception which defaults back to the home bloginfo name.

Would it be easier to try to parse the nav link titles themselves into the function?

Please help if you can!

**UPDATE**

I have completely ditched the previous option and went the following route:

```
<?php if (is_page() || is_single( array( 62, 57, 51, 8 ) )) {

        echo wp_title('');
            }

            else{


            $category = get_the_category(); 
            echo $category[0]->cat_name;
            }?>
```

It is kind of botched but after reading lots of reference material on the wordpress site, I think I am beginning to understand the syntax. So, instead of targeting `bloginfo()` I am now targeting the page title. However I do not want the posts to have a huge title therefore I am making all pages other than top level "`pages`" pick up the first category instead, except for a handful of posts which are in fact custom pages, so need to display the `wp_title` value.

If anyone has any tips on turning this into a more flexible/efficient function please drop a post otherwise I will make this as resolved in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax would be

```
<?php

if ( is_page( 'about' ) || == $post->post_parent ) {    
  bloginfo('about');

} elseif ( is_page( 'work' ) || == $post->post_parent ) {   
  bloginfo('work');

} elseif ( is_page( 'contact' ) || == $post->post_parent ) {    
  bloginfo('contact');

} else { 
  bloginfo('name');
}   

?>
```

but there are no such parameters like about,work,contact to the bloginfo function in wordpress.
For more information on bloginfo, please check the this url -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is nothing on parsing the menu titles/page names as parametres. Is $show a variable? I tried the following `bloginfo(wp_title());`but evidently, it di not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this to filter/change the `name` using `bloginfo` filter (just add this code snippet in your `functions.php` file)

```
function my_custom_blogname( $output, $show )
{
    if( $show == 'name' )
    {
        if( is_page('about') ) $output = 'It\'s my about page';
        if( is_page('work') ) $output = 'It\'s my work page';
        if( is_page('contact') ) $output = 'It\'s my contact page';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_filter('bloginfo', 'my_custom_blogname', 10, 2);
```

**Update :** Also you can check if the page is parent/top lavel page using

```
if( !$post->post_parent ) // To check only if it's a parent/top lavel page
if( is_page('about') && !$post->post_parent ) $output = 'about'; // To check if it's a parent/top lavel page and about page
```

Comment: Sorry Sheikh but I just don't know how to use your code. I added it to the functions.php but cannot call the function in. Like I said I am not a developer, I am basically using logic to try to read what the code does.

Comment: You don't have to call the function manually, instead wherever the function `bloginfo('name')` is called, it'll be filtered automatically.

Comment: Hmm I tried that but it still only calls the website name instead of individual pages. The basic "` <?php wp_title(''); ?>` works, however it picks up every single page even the children, grandchildren, search results etc. I tried filtering it as above but my `== $post->post_parent` condition does not work. :-(